# Can the same in-app purchase be presented form 2 different places in the app?

Tags: in-app-purchase, screenshot, product

I have a consumable product in my app that can be purchased from 2 different places (viewControllers). Do I have to create 2 different products or can I use the same product ID? The reason I'm asking is because when you submit a product for review, you have to attach one and only one screenshot. I have 2 different scenarios for that same product. I can't find any answer on the Web.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: if you end up in the same situation, my app just got approved with one single product. So the answer (to my question) is, no. You don't need to create 2 different products.